# Sort a particular sequence in linear time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am looking at this challenge:

> Given a sequence of integers, sorted by their absolute values, return the sequence sorted by their signed value. The following rules apply:
>
> 1. You can traverse the sequence in only one direction
> 2. You cannot randomly access the elements at any position: you have to start from the first element and traverse.
> 3. you can choose any data structure to take the input of the sequence, on the condition that the data structure does not sort the sequence for you

How can I solve this with a *O(n)* time complexity?

Comment: What does "take the input of the sequence" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible algorithm using a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)):

- In a first iteration push the negative values on the stack.
- Pop values from the stack one by one and output them in that order
- In a second iteration select and output the non-negative values.

Or with a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue):

- Iterate the sequence only once, and:
- When the value is negative push the value in front of the deque
- When the value is non-negative push the value at the back of the deque
- Output the deque by pulling values from the front.